# TFS 2010 cutom build Template

Tags: workflow

I am using vs2010 and I am creating custom tfs2010 build template.
So I want to copy a directory from my Solution root to my build drop location.
In TFS 2008 this looks like this:
`<Exec Command="xcopy &quot;$(SolutionRoot)\&quot;DbLocal\IPA &quot;$(OutDir)&quot;..\Destination"/>`
How do I do this in TFS 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With opened your Build Process Template, find in the Toolbox (Ctrl+Alt+X) under "Team Foundation Build Activities" the one you are after: `CopyDirectory`.
You only have to enter the path to Source & Destination in this form:
[image]

Comment: I have done this far, but I need to get the "SolutionRoot", to write it in the Source, How do I do this?

Comment: There are three variables available: `SourcesDirectory`, `BuildDirectory` & `localProject`. You can check if any of those is a direct hit to what you need, or you can use them to get where you need with `Path` operations.